# android get android library context vs. app context

Tags: java, android, android-library

Now that Android libraries can have resource files, and their own R.java files, they also have their own context as well, right?  Or are the library resources merged with the application resources at compile time?  What context do I use for (Context).getResources().getString(resourcsId) for a string defined in the library's res/values/strings.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The Contexts are still the Application, Activities, and Services.  The library's resources get merged into your own.